# Does enabled policy in GPO take precedence over GPO that is not configured for that policy?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have a primary GPO that is #1 in Link Order.
The Audit Logon Events policy in GPO #1 is not turned on or not defined.

The Audit Logon Events policy in GPO #2 is configured to allow auditing.

I know that normally GPO #1 will take precedence over #2.  But since the policy is not even configured in #1, does that mean #2 kicks in?

Comment: Yes. Verify with gpresult and/or rsop on the target machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Policy 2 settings will be applied.

GPO link order is relevant for settings that are configured in multiple policies. If the settings were configured in Policy 1 then they would take precedence over the settings in Policy 2. Since the settings are not configured in Policy 1 then the settings in Policy 2 will be applied.